# Test class for Case History Related list

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, custom-controller, history-tracking

On a VF Page, I am displaying Case's history related list with a custom tabular format. I am querying Case history object in an Apex class (under Constructor):

```
caseHist = [Select OldValue, NewValue, Field, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Name,
                       CreatedBy.FirstName, CreatedBy.LastName
                       From CaseHistory Where CaseId =:currentCase.Id ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC];
```

Just using a return method to get the data:

```
 public List<CaseHistory> getCaseHistory(){
    return caseHist;
}
```

On VF page:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!caseHistory}" var="casHistory">
                <div class="question-container">
                    <div class="section1">
                        {!casHistory.CreatedBy.LastName}, {!casHistory.CreatedBy.FirstName}
                    </div>
                    <div class="section2" >
                        Changed {!casHistory.Field} from {!casHistory.OldValue} to {!casHistory.NewValue}
                    </div>
                    <div class="section3">
                        {!casHistory.CreatedDate}
                    </div>
                </div>
</apex:repeat>
```

My understanding is: In a test class, we are not actually committing any records to the database to update few fields and get the tracking history for those. Now I am wondering, how could I get 100% of my Apex class's code coverage? Right now, I got 73% covered.

Comment: Why my Google search couldn't find the above question previously? So the simple answer to my question is: NO. 
Thanks @Eric

Comment: My first thought was to use a json object to deserialize into a history record list but the linked answer suggest that does not work. Could try it though have the method deserialize a string into a list of records if in test context or query if not. May be worth s shot to try it

Comment: Could you please share me any post/question that does this deserializing a string using JSON?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Since record is not committed to database, History record is not getting created.

You need to create fake data for CaseHistory (*just like you create the records for Case Object in test method*) and use that data in the test class.

There is an idea [Enable History Tracking for Apex Test Methods](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000h6RwAAI) is available.

Comment: I don't think we can create fake data for CaseHistory object as well:


@sfdcfox: The History tables are ReadOnly, coz I'm guessing they're a little bit like the Salesforce System Fields. To maintain the integrity of the audit trail, they're locked to writes. To be able to write our own history records, we'd need to roll our own History Mechanism, with an object and a trigger.

Comment: You are correct